# Unable to POST via REST API

Tags: c#, rest

This may be too specific of an issue for assistance on, but I'm at a roadblock and don't know where else to turn.

I am POSTing to a website via REST API and their documentation states:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://server_name/api/import/tickets");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer {{access_token}}");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");

var yourArrayOfTickets = new List<Ticket>();
// TODO: populate the list

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(yourArrayOfTickets);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I am sending

```
public static void MakeTicket(string token, string url,
            string clientName, string clientLocation, 
            string ticketSource, string ticketType, 
            string title, string priority, string status, 
            string details, DateTime openDate, string queue)
        {
            TicketBody ticketBody = new TicketBody();
            ticketBody.ClientName = clientName;
            ticketBody.ClientLocation = clientLocation;
            ticketBody.TicketSource = ticketSource;
            ticketBody.TicketType = ticketType;
            ticketBody.Title = title;
            ticketBody.Priority = priority;
            ticketBody.Status = status;
            ticketBody.Details = details;
            ticketBody.OpenDate = Convert.ToString(openDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
            ticketBody.Queue = queue;

            var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ticketBody);
            var bodyList = new List<string>();
            bodyList.Add(body);
            var client = new RestClient(url + "/import/tickets");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");

            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddBody(bodyList);

            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        }
```

My bodyList JSON looks like
[image]

My response looks like[image]

Their documentation states the required fields are:[image]

The error message is too vague to help me, it just says I'm missing something but doesn't say what, and as far as I can tell, I'm passing in everything it needs.

Comment: I should mention that url, token and anything else that's needed is working fine. There are several GET requests that require the same/similar info and they all work fine. So it's in the rest of the data that I'm passing that the error exists.

Comment: You have not included the required parameter `AssgineeUsername`. If you are specifying `Queue`, try passing it as empty, but include it in request

Comment: I'm passing in Queue, so need for AssigneeUsername per their docs.

Comment: `AssigneeUsername` can be left empty, but it is `Required` parameter

Comment: Just added that to confirm and no change.

Comment: ok. Are you passing the object in array in body? Because in screenshot, you are showing object of index 0 `[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I was building out the JSON object incorrectly for this. Instead of serializing the entire object, it needs to be a list.

```
Ticket ticketBody = new Ticket
            {
                ClientName = clientName,
                ClientLocation = clientLocation,
                TicketSource = ticketSource,
                TicketType = ticketType,
                Title = title,
                Priority = priority,
                Status = status,
                Details = details,
                OpenDate = Convert.ToString(openDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")),
                Queue = queue
            };

            List<Ticket> bodyList = new List<Ticket>();
            bodyList.Add(ticketBody);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation screenshot, you have not included the required parameter `AssgineeUsername`. If you are specifying `Queue`, try passing it as empty, but include it in request.

```
ticketBody.Queue = queue;
ticketBody.AssgineeUsername = "";
```